# Inserting multiple CLOBs in PHP with Oracle Database

Tags: php, oracle

I would like to ask everyone, I can save a clob field at present, but I want to try to save 3 clob fields at a time, but it will still fail. Only 1 field is saved. For now, I don't consider the syntax Under attack
I would like to ask how I want to save 3 clob fields at a time. How should I modify or suggest? Thank you?

```
$TPsql = "INSERT INTO test(
                value1,value2,value3)
                 VALUES (
                 EMPTY_CLOB(), EMPTY_CLOB(), EMPTY_CLOB())
                                                                                     RETURNING  value1 INTO   :value1";

$Stid = oci_parse($conn, $TPsql);

$clob=oci_new_descriptor($conn,OCI_D_LOB);

  oci_bind_by_name($Stid,":value1",$clob,-1,OCI_B_CLOB);
  oci_bind_by_name($Stid,":value2",$clob,-1,OCI_B_CLOB);
  oci_bind_by_name($Stid,":value3",$clob,-1,OCI_B_CLOB);
  
 $result = oci_execute($Stid,OCI_NO_AUTO_COMMIT);
 
  $clob->save($value1);
  $clob->save($value2);
   $clob->save($value3);
    oci_commit($conn);
```

Comment: value1,value2,value3 are column names, not parameters.  I think your insert is wrong.  your insert is using empty_clob() as the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this (untested code):

```php
  $TPsql = "INSERT INTO test(
                value1,value2,value3)
                 VALUES (
                 EMPTY_CLOB(), EMPTY_CLOB(), EMPTY_CLOB())                                                                                  
  RETURNING  value1,value2,value3 INTO :value1, :value2, :value3";

  $Stid = oci_parse($conn, $TPsql);

  $clob1=oci_new_descriptor($conn,OCI_D_LOB);
  $clob2=oci_new_descriptor($conn,OCI_D_LOB);
  $clob3=oci_new_descriptor($conn,OCI_D_LOB);

  oci_bind_by_name($Stid,":value1",$clob1,-1,OCI_B_CLOB);
  oci_bind_by_name($Stid,":value2",$clob2,-1,OCI_B_CLOB);
  oci_bind_by_name($Stid,":value3",$clob3,-1,OCI_B_CLOB);
  
  $result = oci_execute($Stid,OCI_NO_AUTO_COMMIT);
 
  $clob1->save($value1);
  $clob2->save($value2);
  $clob3->save($value3);
  oci_commit($conn);
```